# Storing negative value in Remaining Amount instead of Real amount ?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table (i-e) `payments`(`Pay_ID`, `Order_ID`, `User_ID`, `Bank_Name`, `Account_No`, `Total_Amount`, `Paid_Amount`, `Remaining_Amount`, `DateTime` 
I'm updating the table with this code

```
public function update()
{
$sess_id = $this->session->userdata('tot_amnt');
$Bank_Name = $this->input->post('Bank_Name'); 
$Account_No = $this->input->post('Account_No'); 
$Paid_Amount = $this->input->post('Paid_Amount'); 
$qq = "UPDATE `payments`
            SET Bank_Name = '".$Bank_Name."',
                Account_No = '".$Account_No."',
                Paid_Amount = '".$Paid_Amount."',
                Remaining_Amount = '".$sess_id."' - '".$Paid_Amount."'
            ORDER BY `DateTime` DESC LIMIT 1";
return $this->db->query($qq);
}
```

here in $sess_id i stored the MAX(`DateTime`) from `payments` table in controller (i-e)

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT `Total_Amount` FROM `payments` WHERE     `DateTime` = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM `payments`)')->result(); 
$new_data=array(
  'tot_amnt' => $query
  );
$this->session->set_userdata($new_data);
```

Now every thing works fine but it shows me two errors, 
First error:  Array to string conversion in pay_model  line No: 22 which is:

```
Remaining_Amount = '".$sess_id."' - '".$Paid_Amount."'
```

and 2nd error:  It insert negative value in Remaining_Amount like  -200 or something else. I'm attaching snaps with it.. Thank you.
Snaps are: 
[image][image][image]

Comment: why are doing this '".$sess_id."' - '".$Paid_Amount."' ? is this some substraction

Comment: The HTML element `Paid_Amount` seems to have `name="Paid_Amount[]"`. Post your HTML here.

Comment: #ddw147 i passed $sess_id because it contains the Total Amount .... and yes, it is subtraction

Comment: #pupil  it is   
 <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label> Paid Amount:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Paid_Amount"  class="form-control" id="email" required  style="width: 50%;" >
                        </div>
                    </div>

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your `$sess_id` is actually an array so it prints the word `Array` and that's why the calculation in `Remaining_Amount` is something like `Array - 200 = -200`.

I see that `$sess_id` is coming from `$sess_id = $this->session->userdata('tot_amnt');` so maybe you've assigned the `tot_amnt` value like

```
$tot_amnt = array(
                   'tot_amnt'  => 1112
               );
$this->session->set_userdata($tot_amnt);
```

Instead you could add userdata one value at a time:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('tot_amnt ', 1112);
```

Comment: Let me try it #Stoyan

Comment: Print the `tot_amnt` value using `print_r($this->session->userdata('tot_amnt'))` and see what's the result!

Comment: It gives me this... Which i have got before... same same..
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Price] => 123 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Price] => 456 ) )

Comment: So I was right - `tot_amnt` is an array and you are trying to use it as a string. It even has two objects in it. The questions are "Is it by mistake or with purpose?" and "Which values do you need for your calculation?"

Comment: Let me paraphrase - Is there a reason that you have two prices in the `tot_amnt` and if yes - which value do you need for calculating the `Remaining_Amount`?